# Sqoop Job Exception

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am getting the following Exception when I'm trying to List the Sqoop JOBS.

I'm not able to create the Soop jobs because of this exception:

> root@ubuntu:/usr/lib/sqoop/conf# sqoop job --list 16/04/11 01:51:44
>   ERROR tool.JobTool: I/O error performing job operation:
>   java.io.IOException: Exception creating SQL connection    at
>   com.cloudera.sqoop.metastore.hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage.init(HsqldbJobStorage.java:220)
>     at
>   com.cloudera.sqoop.metastore.hsqldb.AutoHsqldbStorage.open(AutoHsqldbStorage.java:113)
>     at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.JobTool.run(JobTool.java:279)    at
>   com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:146)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)     at
>   com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:182)     at
>   com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:221)  at
>   com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:230)  at
>   com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:239) Caused by:
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: General error: java.lang.ClassFormatError: >Truncated class file
>     at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
>     at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.(Unknown Source)
>     at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>     at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
>     at com.cloudera.sqoop.metastore.hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage.init(HsqldbJobStorage.java:>180)
>       ... 8 more

**Sqoop Version:** 1.3.0-cdh3u5

Please help

Commands used as below:

```
sqoop job --list

sqoop job --create sqoopjob21 -- import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/mysql1 --table emp --target-dir /importjob21 ;
```

Comment: please share the command you fired.

Comment: Commands used:  

sqoop job --list

sqoop job --create sqoopjob21 -- import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/mysql1 --table emp --target-dir /importjob21 ;

Comment: is this full error log or more lines after `General error: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file`?

Comment: Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: General error: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file
 at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
 at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
 at com.cloudera.sqoop.metastore.hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage.init(HsqldbJobStorage.java:180)
 ... 8 more

Comment: are you using remote metastore for sqoop?

Comment: No , using the Metastore present on the local machine with came with sqoop package

Comment: can you try `sqoop job --list -verbose` and let me know the output

Comment: I am getting the same exception :(

Comment: `-verbose` is for detailed logs. so you got any more useful logs?

Comment: yeah it is for detailed logging , but i got the same error ..

Answer (score 0):

This may possibly be because sqoop cannot find the hsqldb which it uses to store job information. Check if you have "metastore.db.script" file in the sqoop installed directory, if not create it.
Create a file named "metastore.db.script" and put the following lines

```
CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC AUTHORIZATION DBA
CREATE MEMORY TABLE SQOOP_ROOT(VERSION INTEGER,PROPNAME VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,PROPVAL VARCHAR(256),CONSTRAINT SQOOP_ROOT_UNQ UNIQUE(VERSION,PROPNAME))
CREATE MEMORY TABLE SQOOP_SESSIONS(JOB_NAME VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,PROPNAME VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,PROPVAL VARCHAR(1024),PROPCLASS VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,CONSTRAINT SQOOP_SESSIONS_UNQ UNIQUE(JOB_NAME,PROPNAME,PROPCLASS))
CREATE USER SA PASSWORD ""
GRANT DBA TO SA
SET WRITE_DELAY 10
SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
INSERT INTO SQOOP_ROOT VALUES(NULL,'sqoop.hsqldb.job.storage.version','0')
INSERT INTO SQOOP_ROOT VALUES(0,'sqoop.hsqldb.job.info.table','SQOOP_SESSIONS')
```

Now create "metastore.db.properties" file and put these lines

```
#HSQL Database Engine 1.8.0.10
#Fri Aug 04 14:07:10 IST 2017
hsqldb.script_format=0
runtime.gc_interval=0
sql.enforce_strict_size=false
hsqldb.cache_size_scale=8
readonly=false
hsqldb.nio_data_file=true
hsqldb.cache_scale=14
version=1.8.0
hsqldb.default_table_type=memory
hsqldb.cache_file_scale=1
hsqldb.log_size=200
modified=no
hsqldb.cache_version=1.7.0
hsqldb.original_version=1.8.0
hsqldb.compatible_version=1.8.0
```

Now create a directory named ".sqoop" if not already created and put these two files there. Now run your job.